# Columns.Add that uses lambda expression

Tags: c#

I am working with some code that uses `Columns.Add` in conjunction with a lambda expression and would like to understand why/how it works.  Here is a code snippet:

```
public ReportGrid(List<ReportRowDataContract> items)
            : base(items)
        {    
                if (items[0].ReportData1 != null)
                {
                    if (items[0].ReportData1.DecimalValue != null)
                    {

                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData1.Name).Encoded(false).
                            Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                                m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat)) ? Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString("N") : Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat));

                        if (items[0].ReportData1.SumValue || items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData1.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue,
                                        DecimalValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (items[0].ReportData1.IntValue != null)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.IntValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData1.Name);
                        if (items[0].ReportData1.SumValue || items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData1.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData1.AvgValue,
                                        IntValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.StringValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData1.Name);
                    }
                }
                if (items[0].ReportData2 != null)
                {
                    if (items[0].ReportData2.DecimalValue != null)
                    {
                    Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.DecimalValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name).Encoded(false).
                       Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                           m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@m.ReportData2.DisplayFormat)) ? Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData2.DecimalValue).ToString("N") : Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData2.DecimalValue).ToString(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat));

                    if (items[0].ReportData2.SumValue || items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData2.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue,
                                        DecimalValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else if (items[0].ReportData2.IntValue != null)
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.IntValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name);
                        if (items[0].ReportData2.SumValue || items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue)
                        {
                            displaySummary = true;
                            SummaryData.Add(
                                new ReportDataDataContract
                                    {
                                        Name = items[0].ReportData2.Name,
                                        AvgValue = items[0].ReportData2.AvgValue,
                                        IntValue = 0
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.StringValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name);
                    }

                }
```

This method consists of code that repeats itself out to ReportData6, changing only the ReportData field name with each repetition.

Here is the `ReportRowDataContract` class:

```
public class ReportRowDataContract
{   
    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData1 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData2 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData3 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData4 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData5 { get; set; }

    public ReportDataDataContract ReportData6 { get; set; }

    // an indexed property - for accessing report data fields by index
    public ReportDataDataContract this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return new ReportDataDataContract[]
            {
              ReportData1,
              ReportData2,
              ReportData3,
              ReportData4,
              ReportData5,
              ReportData6                  
            }[i];
        }
    }

    public int GetReportDataFieldCount()
    {
        return 6;
    }        
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot change the structure of this class so I'm trying to convert the first code block into a method that loops.  However, I'm stuck on what the Columns.Add is actually adding to.

Here is my code thus far:

```
    public ReportGrid(List<ReportRowDataContract> items)
        : base(items)
    {
        // get count of how many fields exist in ReportRowDataContract                     
        int reportDataFieldCount = (new ReportRowDataContract()).GetReportDataFieldCount();

        // create columns for grid for each field in ReportRowDataContract
        //foreach (ReportRowDataContract item in items)
        //{
            int i = 0;
            while (i < reportDataFieldCount)
            {
                AddGridColumn(items[0][i]);
                i++;
            }
        //}
    }

    private void AddGridColumn(ReportDataDataContract reportColumn)
    {
        if (reportColumn != null)
        {
            if (reportColumn.DecimalValue != null)
            {
                Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name).Encoded(false).
                    Sanitized(false).RenderValueAs(
                        m => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat)) ?
                            Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString("N") :
                            Convert.ToDecimal(@m.ReportData1.DecimalValue).ToString(@m.ReportData1.DisplayFormat));

                if (reportColumn.SumValue || reportColumn.AvgValue)
                {
                    displaySummary = true;
                    SummaryData.Add(
                        new ReportDataDataContract
                        {
                            Name = reportColumn.Name,
                            AvgValue = reportColumn.AvgValue,
                            DecimalValue = 0
                        });
                }
            }
            else if (reportColumn.IntValue != null)
            {
                Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.IntValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name);
                if (reportColumn.SumValue || reportColumn.AvgValue)
                {
                    displaySummary = true;
                    SummaryData.Add(
                        new ReportDataDataContract
                        {
                            Name = reportColumn.Name,
                            AvgValue = reportColumn.AvgValue,
                            IntValue = 0
                        });
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData1.StringValue).Titled(reportColumn.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the `AddGridColumn` method the part that is problematic is `m => m.ReportData1`.  It's not dynamic so the first loop through is fine but on the second loop through an exception is thrown: `System.ArgumentException  {"Column 'ReportData1.StringValue' already exist in the grid"}`.  I know the `m.ReportData1` needs to be changed or the approach modified...just don't know how to go about it.

**Edit #1:** Disabled the `foreach` per VitezslavSimon's insight.  The same exception message is being thrown.

**Edit #2:** Base class of grid (I think).

```
public class Grid<T> : GridBase<T>, IGrid where T : class
    {
        public Grid(IEnumerable<T> items);
        public Grid(IQueryable<T> items);

        public IGridColumnCollection<T> Columns { get; }
        public bool DefaultFilteringEnabled { get; set; }
        public bool DefaultSortEnabled { get; set; }
        public virtual int DisplayingItemsCount { get; }
        public bool EnablePaging { get; set; }
        public string Language { get; set; }
        public IGridPager Pager { get; set; }
        public GridRenderOptions RenderOptions { get; set; }
        public ISanitizer Sanitizer { get; set; }
        public override IGridSettingsProvider Settings { get; set; }

        public virtual void AutoGenerateColumns();
        protected internal virtual IEnumerable<T> GetItemsToDisplay();
    }
```

Comment: Please for the love of god don't put (that much) logic in your constructors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add columns only once there. Try to help it by declaring a flag there. It also depends how your grid component is working behind.

Your code with draft of proposed change:

```
public ReportGrid(List<ReportRowDataContract> items)
    : base(items)
{
    // get count of how many fields exist in ReportRowDataContract                     
    int reportDataFieldCount = (new ReportRowDataContract()).GetReportDataFieldCount();

    // create columns for grid for each field in ReportRowDataContract
    bool flag = true;

    foreach (ReportRowDataContract item in items)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (flag) {
        while (i < reportDataFieldCount)
        {
            AddGridColumn(items[0][i]);
            i++;
        }
        flag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes - good point.  I will try removing the `foreach` completely and just use the `while` block.  However, the `Columns.Add` and lambda expression dilemma remains.

Comment: Write if problem has moved after the change.

Comment: The end result has not changed - still getting the same exception message after updating the code.

Comment: 1st code example from your question: 2 rows here: `Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.IntValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name);` and                     `else
                    {
                        Columns.Add(m => m.ReportData2.StringValue).Titled(items[0].ReportData2.Name);
                    }` Ma apologies for formatting. I am newbie here and I have problem to provide good formatting in sub comments.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow your last comment.  The `AddGridColumn` method is intended to loop through each of the ReportDataX fields and add columns to the grid.

Comment: Try to comment all `SummaryData.Add(` calls with whole blocks around if your exception will remain there. Or change part by this way: `SummaryData.Add(
                        new ReportDataDataContract
                        {
                            Name = reportColumn.Name + "S",` I am not sure if it can helps to you, but I don't know base class of your grid currently. Do you have access to source code of base class?

Comment: I probably have access to the base class of the grid.  I am new at C# though - how do I tell what the base class is called?

Comment: `public ReportGrid(List<ReportRowDataContract> items) : base(items)` is contained within a class called `public class ReportGrid : Grid<ReportRowDataContract>`.  I'm guessing `Grid` is the base class so the code for that class has been added to my original post as Edit #2.  If this is not the base class, let me know and I'll dig further.

Comment: OK, your explanation confirms that `Grid` is the base class.

Comment: Yes, you are right, its: Grid<ReportRowDataContract>, its class with one generic parameter here ( if you want some description of it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes ).

Comment: Is your application written in WinForms?

Comment: The app is not written in WinForms.

Comment: Components are vary depends on used sub technology. Another ones are: ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC or WPF?

Comment: I think it's .NET but not sure of anything more specific.  Is there a way I can look it up?  We use C# backend and HTML/CSS/JS in a browser front end, if that helps at all.

Comment: Ok in this stack WPF is out so its web application (ASP.NET WebForms (.aspx files), ASP.NET MVC (.cshtml) ). Do you have a chance to see page template in designer in Visual Studio?

Comment: There are several view files with the .cshtml extension so I'm thinking it's ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: In that case code seems to be complicated for me and it seems its probably not fitting to your needs. Are you using any special components (e.g.: inhouse  company frame solution)? Look for example to this blog post: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1114208/Beginners-Guide-for-Creating-GridView-in-ASP-NET-M if it possibly can have sense for you to change your solution in this way.

Comment: I suspect you are right about it being too complicated.  Not sure if any of the components were built in-house.  I'll check out the link you provided and see if there's a better approach than the current design.  Thanks very much for all your help!

Comment: Tell if it helped a bit or put other question about it. :)